# How do I target the nearest div of a class with this nested HTML?

Tags: jquery

I have a structure like so:

```
<header class="entry-header">
    <div class="entry-before-title">
    <h3 class="entry-title">
        <div class="playTag">
            <img/>
        </div>
        </h3>
        </div>
</header>
<div class="entry-summary"></div>
<footer>
    <p class="entry-byline"></p>
</footer>
```

And I have code for the `playTag` class which is trying to toggle margin-left of `entry-byline`:

```
$('.playTag').click(function() {            
        $(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.entry-byline').css({marginLeft:'200px'});
        return false;
});
```

My problem is that this is not successfully targeting the `entry-byline` nearest to `playTag`. (It's not targeting an `entry-byline` at all actually).  Can I please get help with targeting the nearest `entry-byline` successfully in this click code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DOM traversal isn't quite right. You need to find the parent `header` to the clicked `.playTag`, which can be done more simply and robustly using `closest()` instead of chaining `parent()` calls.

From there you can retrieve the sibling `footer` element and then `find()` the `.entry-byline` within that.

I would also suggest using CSS classes to amend the styling through JS. This is to avoid having to place CSS logic within JS, which is a violation of the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle.

```js
$('.playTag').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('header').siblings('footer').find('.entry-byline').toggleClass('foo');
});
```

```css
.foo { margin-left: 200px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="entry-header">
  <div class="entry-before-title">
    <h3 class="entry-title">
      <div class="playTag">
        playTag
        <img/>
      </div>
    </h3>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="entry-summary">entry-summary</div>
<footer>
  <p class="entry-byline">entry-byline</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: A_m_a_z_i_n_g, thank you so much for the quick and super helpful reply. I had no idea you could navigate so efficiently with those keywords. I appreciate this! & I will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: just saw the CSS advice follow-up, awesome, thank you so much

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest working with a *delegate listener* so it also works for dynamically added elements.

Here's the vanilla JS version:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('.playTag')) {
    const byLine = event.target
      .closest('.entry-header')
      .nextElementSibling
      .nextElementSibling
      .querySelector('.entry-byline');
    byLine.classList.toggle('ml-200');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
.ml-200 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<header class="entry-header">
  <div class="entry-before-title">
    <h3 class="entry-title">
      <div class="playTag">
        playTag
      </div>
    </h3>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="entry-summary"></div>
<footer>
  <p class="entry-byline">entry-byline</p>
</footer>
<header class="entry-header">
  <div class="entry-before-title">
    <h3 class="entry-title">
      <div class="playTag">
        playTag
      </div>
    </h3>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="entry-summary"></div>
<footer>
  <p class="entry-byline">entry-byline</p>
</footer>
```